# Gridview of images from internet and out of memory

Tags: android, memory

I am trying to display some images in a gridView, this images come from a research on an ElasticSearch server. So I have a textfield + button on my first activity and when I click on the button some images in relation with the keyword in the textfield are printed in a gridview.

Until now I can do my research and some images are displayed in the gridView, but my application crash (outofmemory) after some scroll down/up or if I do others researches. I guess I have to fix this two problems separately. 
For the first one (scroll up/down) I want to memorize the bitmap in the cache (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).
For the second problem I don't know what to do. All advices/ideas are welcome.

When I memorize the image in the cache, I have still a problem, when I scroll down and after I scroll up no image are displayed anymore and the is no error in catlog.

AndroidGridLayoutActivity.java

```
public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {
ImageAdapter imgAdapter =new ImageAdapter(this);
GridView gridView;
private static LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

     // Get memory class of this device, exceeding this amount will throw an
    // OutOfMemory exception.
    final int memClass = ((ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }
    };

}

public void sendMessage(View view){

    imgAdapter.clearmThumbIds();

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    try {
        eSearchElastic.ESE(imgAdapter,message,gridView,0);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("SendMessage  is ok poiuur ca");



}

public static void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}

}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
static private List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context mContext;
Bitmap bmImg;

static private List<String> mThumbIds = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addmThumbIds(String url) {
    mThumbIds.add(url);
}

public void clearmThumbIds() {
    mThumbIds.clear();
}

public String getmThumbIds(int position) {
    return mThumbIds.get(position);
}

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    System.out.println("Poisition " + position);
    downloadFile(imageView, mThumbIds.get(position));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(135, 135));
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 1, 0);

    return imageView;
}

void downloadFile(final ImageView imageView, final String fileUrl) {

    AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> task = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            System.out.println("TEST 1 : begining background");
            if (!urlList.contains(fileUrl)) {
                urlList.add(fileUrl);

                URL myFileUrl = null;
                try {
                    myFileUrl = new URL((String) params[0]);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                            .openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("TEST 2");
                bmImg = AndroidGridLayoutActivity
                        .getBitmapFromMemCache(fileUrl);

            }
            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            System.out.println("TEST 2 : begining postexecute");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
            if (!urlList.contains(fileUrl)) {
                AndroidGridLayoutActivity.addBitmapToMemoryCache(fileUrl,
                        bmImg);
            }


        }
    };
    task.execute(fileUrl);

}

 }
```

gridlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
android:id="@+id/searchBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/Search_hint"
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/button_send"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="sendMessage" />


<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In case of need eSearchElastic.java

```
public class eSearchElastic {

static private List<String> idRowKey = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void ESE(final ImageAdapter imgAdapter, final String keyword,
        final GridView gridView,final int from) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        private String rowKey;
        private int i =0;
        private int imageAlreadyPrinted =0;
        private int size=10;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String server = "server";
            String index = "images";
            String type = "images_schema_1";

            System.out.println("\n\n KEYWORD " + keyword + "\n\n");
            String query = "{\"sort\" : [ {\"confidence_level\" : {\"order\" : \"desc\"} }],\"from\" : "+from+", \"size\" : "+size+",\"query\" : {\"text_phrase\" : { \"keyword\" : \""
                                + keyword
                                + "\"}},\"filter\" : {\"numeric_range\" : {\"confidence_level\" : { \"from\" : 10, \"to\" : 100, \"include_lower\" : true, \"include_upper\" : true}}}}'";

            ElasticConnection connection = new ElasticConnection(server, index, type);
            ElasticQuery elasticQuery = new ElasticQuery(query); 
            ElasticResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = elasticQuery.getAnswer(connection);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            String[] fields = { "url"};
            List<ElasticResult> results = null;
            try {
                results = response.getAnswer(fields);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (ElasticResult res : results) {
                System.out.println("ICI  "+from+ " " + res.getField("url"));
                rowKey = res.getId();
                System.out.println(res.getId());

                if (rowKey != null) {

                        if (idRowKey.contains(rowKey)) {
                            if(imageAlreadyPrinted<size && i==size-1)
                                try {
                                    ESE(imgAdapter,keyword,gridView,from+10);
                                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            System.out.println(rowKey);
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            imageAlreadyPrinted++;
                            addidRowKey(rowKey);
                            imgAdapter.addmThumbIds(res.getField("url"));
                        }
                    }
                i++;    
            }

            System.out.println("-----FIN esearch");
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            gridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
        }

    };
    task.execute();

}

public static void addidRowKey(String url) {
    idRowKey.add(url);
}

public void cleaidRowKey() {
    idRowKey.clear();
}

public String getidRowKey(int position) {
    return idRowKey.get(position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lazy Ninja is right, key is lazy image loading. Moreover, to increase the performance of your adapter, you should consider multi-threading it. There is a very good reference on [Android Developer's blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). Simpler than the example @Lazy Ninja gave.

It's hard to understand at the beginning, but by far the best approach.

Also, you should consider using an Android Service more than an asynctask for loading data from the network. [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) can help you to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use lazy image loading. Here is a very good example: [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)